# Android sqlite database null pointer exception

Tags: android, sqlite

I am getting a null pointer exception when I try to insert data into my sqlite database in my Android application.  I've looked at the code and everything seems to be in order and I'm baffled as to why I'm getting the null pointer exception. The code is as follows:

```
import java.sql.Blob;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;


public class DBAdapter {

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_STUDENTNAME = "studentname";
    public static final String KEY_DOB = "dob";
    public static final String KEY_ADDRESS1 = "address1";
    public static final String KEY_ADDRESS2 = "address2";
    public static final String KEY_TOWN = "town";
    public static final String KEY_POSTCODE = "postcode";
    public static final String KEY_PHONE = "phone";  
    public static final String KEY_STUDENT_PIC = "studentpic";  

    private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter"; 



    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "studentDB3";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "tblstudents";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table tblstudents (id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "studentname text not null, dob text not null, " 
        + "address1 text not null, address2 text not null, "
        + "town text not null, postcode text not null, "
        + " phone text not null, studentpic blob);";

    private final Context context; 

    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBAdapter(Context ctx) 
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
        {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, 
        int newVersion) 
        {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion 
                    + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tblStudents");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }    

    //---opens the database---
    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException 
    {
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    //---closes the database---    
    public void close() 
    {
        DBHelper.close();
    }

    //---insert a title into the database---
    public long insertStudent(String studentname, String dob, String address1, String address2, String town, String postcode, String phone, byte[] studentpic) 
    {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_STUDENTNAME, studentname);
        initialValues.put(KEY_DOB, dob);
        initialValues.put(KEY_ADDRESS1, address1);
        initialValues.put(KEY_ADDRESS2, address2);
        initialValues.put(KEY_TOWN, town);
        initialValues.put(KEY_POSTCODE, postcode);
        initialValues.put(KEY_PHONE, phone);
        initialValues.put(KEY_STUDENT_PIC, studentpic);

        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    //---deletes a particular title---
    public boolean deleteTitle(long rowId) 
    {
        return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + 
                "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    //---retrieves all the titles---
    public Cursor getAllStudents() 
    {
        return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                KEY_ROWID, 
                KEY_STUDENTNAME,
                KEY_DOB,
                KEY_ADDRESS1,
                KEY_ADDRESS2,
                KEY_TOWN,
                KEY_POSTCODE,
                KEY_PHONE,
                KEY_STUDENT_PIC
                            }, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null);
    }

    //---retrieves a particular title---
    public Cursor getStudent(long rowId) throws SQLException 
    {
        Cursor mCursor =
                db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                        KEY_ROWID, 
                        KEY_STUDENTNAME,
                        KEY_DOB,
                        KEY_ADDRESS1,
                        KEY_ADDRESS2,
                        KEY_TOWN,
                        KEY_POSTCODE,
                        KEY_PHONE,
                        KEY_STUDENT_PIC
                        }, 
                        KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, 
                        null,
                        null, 
                        null, 
                        null, 
                        null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    //---updates a student---
    public boolean updateStudent(long rowId, String studentname, 
    String dob, String address1, String address2, String town,
    String postcode, String phone, byte[] studentpic) 
    {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_STUDENTNAME, studentname);
        args.put(KEY_DOB, dob);
        args.put(KEY_ADDRESS1, address1);
        args.put(KEY_ADDRESS2, address2);
        args.put(KEY_TOWN, town);
        args.put(KEY_POSTCODE, postcode);
        args.put(KEY_PHONE, phone);
        args.put(KEY_STUDENT_PIC, studentpic);

        return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, 
                         KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }




}
```

---

Comment: What line do you get your exception at? It would tell a lot about its cause.

Comment: copy and post your logcat here. from DDMS perspective. `Eclipse > Window > show View > other > DDMS`

Answer (score 1):

In Android, the ID column should be `_id`, not `id` as you have set:

```
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "id";
```

It may be worth looking at.